# How to normalize data in a tensorflow time series with respect to the last element

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to follow the [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/time_series) from tensorflow on time series forecasting. I have some temperature data that varies a lot and as such, I don't actually want to forecast the actual value, just how much it has changed compared to the last element.

Let's imagine that I have a time series training data point of type (input, label): ([8, 7, 5, 9, 11, 10], [12]) and I would like to convert this to a data point where everything is normalized by the last entry in the input. In this concrete example, I would like a data point that looks like this: ([0.8, 0.7, 0.5, 0.9, 1.1, 1.0], [1.2]).

Following the tutorial I am able to create a dataset of windows from the original temperature data collected at a fixed interval. This creates a dataset of tensors, however I am not allowed to modify the values in these tensors. As such, I can't just loop over all the windows in the created dataset and then normalize by dividing by the last value in the input array. Furthermore, I can't normalize the data before the dataset is created as I need the window structure. How can I normalize my data in such a way with respect to each window?

My guess is that it needs to be done after the dataset, and therefore the windows, have been created. So somewhere in this function, maybe:

```
def make_dataset(self, data):
    data = np.array(data, dtype=np.float32)
    ds = tf.keras.utils.timeseries_dataset_from_array(
        data=data,
        targets=None,
        sequence_length=self.total_window_size,
        sequence_stride=1,
        shuffle=True,
        batch_size=32,)

    ds = ds.map(self.split_window)

    return ds
```

Answer (score 0):

one way to do this is to use a data generator and you can implement the logic that you want inside, like divide by the biggest input in each batch, here an example of how to do so :

```
import numpy as np
my_array = np.arange(1024)

def generate_sequence(generate_data,batch_size=16,sequence_length=8):
    list_of_x = []
    list_of_y = []
    while True:
        for i in range(len(generate_data)//sequence_length):
            born_inf = i * sequence_length
            born_sup = (i+1) * sequence_length
            current_data = generate_data[born_inf:born_sup]
            max_n = np.max(current_data)
            list_of_x.append(current_data/max_n)
            list_of_y.append(generate_data[min(born_sup+1,len(generate_data)-1)]/max_n)
        if len(list_of_x) == batch_size:
            yield np.array(list_of_x),np.array(list_of_y)
            list_of_x = []
            lst_of_y = []
```